# Added ajax to a Link but its not working

Tags: 7, ajax

I added a class `use-ajax` to a link but Its not updating the wrapper `div. My Code is:

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items['testing'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'articlenodeform',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  $items['customajaxcallback'] = array(
   'page callback' => 'custom_ajaxcallback',
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function articlenodeform(){
   drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax'); 
   drupal_add_js('misc/ajax.js');
   $link = l(t('Say Hello'), 'customajaxcallback/ajax', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'use-ajax')));
   return '<div>'.$link.'</div><div id="sayinghello"></div>';
}

function custom_ajaxcallback($type = 'ajax') {
  if($type == 'ajax') {
    $output = t('Hello World!');
    $command = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#sayinghello', $output);
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#ajax_command' => $commands);
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
  else{
    return t("Hello world in new page.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it : 
The problem was in my callback function :

```
function custom_ajaxcallback($type = 'ajax') {
  if($type == 'ajax') {
    $output = t('Hello World!');
    $command = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#sayinghello', $output);
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands); --> In this line
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
  else{
    return t("Hello world in new page.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to this:

```
$link = l(t('Say Hello'), 'customajaxcallback/ajax', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax'))));
```

class element itself must also be an array.
read about it [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

Comment: `div` still not rendering.

Comment: which div you trying to add that `use-ajax` class? `l` function adds that class to `a` tag

Comment: yeah but after click the link it should print `Hello World` in `<div id="sayinghello"></div>`.

Comment: try to set `access callback` to true(Or try the permission better fitting your needs) in `custom_menu` and also set `'type'     => MENU_CALLBACK`

Comment: I am logged in as admin so no need for `access callback` and i added the `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK` but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items['testing'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'articlenodeform',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  $items['customajaxcallback/%'] = array(
   'page callback' => 'custom_ajaxcallback',
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}

function articlenodeform(){
   drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax'); 
   $link = l(t('Say Hello'), 'customajaxcallback/nojs', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'use-ajax')));
   return '<div>'.$link.'</div><div id="sayinghello"></div>';
}

function custom_ajaxcallback($ajax) {
  if($ajax == 'ajax') {
    $output = t('Hello World!');
    $command = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#sayinghello', $output);
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#ajax_command' => $commands);
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
  else{
    return t("Hello world in new page.");
  }
}
```

**edit: If you noticed, there were several changes made in the code.**

1. link has been changed to `customajaxcallback/nojs`
2. hook menu is now `customajaxcallback/%`
3. We pass argument 1  to the callback function custom_ajaxcallback `'page arguments' => array(1),`
4. Callback function has been changed by removing the default value and making it look like this `custom_ajaxcallback($ajax)`

Comment: its showing the error: `An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 404
Debugging information follows.
Path: /drupal7/customajaxcallback/ajax
StatusText: Not Found`